# JavaFX: Get position of tiles in TilePane?

Tags: java, javafx-8

Is there a way to determine the position(x and y) of a tile within the tilePane?

Comment: Use [layoutX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#layoutXProperty) and [layoutY](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#layoutYProperty).

Comment: Are you after layout position (e.g. 200 pixels across from top left, 300 pixels down from top left) or ordinal position (e.g. 2nd column, 3rd row) in the tilepane?

Comment: im after the layout position.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: i have the tilepane within a scrollpane. Based on the position of a particular tile i want to scroll to that tile